# PhoneGap - MVC - File Upload - Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync throws System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path

Tags: c#, cordova, iis, file-upload, model-view-controller

I have a PhoneGap app running on Android & iOS that allows users to take a photo and upload it to an MVC service.  This all works fine except from time to time when it throws the following exception.

```
System.IO.IOException: Error writing MIME multipart body part to output
stream. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The stream provider of type
'MyStreamProvider' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentException:
Illegal characters in path.
```

I believe the culprit is users of Samsung Galaxy 4 - but I am not able to confirm that 100%.  It seems almost like the filename that the device submits is not compatible with the Windows filename rules but I am unsure how to get around this.

Here is the full code:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> EnterSweep()
{
  // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
  if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
  {
      throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
  }

  string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
  string photoDirectory = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Photos");

  var provider = new MyStreamProvider(root);

  try
  {
    //This is the code that bombs
    await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    MyLogger.Error("Error uploading file", e);
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
  }


  foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
  {
    RenameAndLogFile(file.LocalFileName, provider, photoDirectory);
  }

  return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Here is the full stack trace....

```
System.IO.IOException: Error writing MIME multipart body part to output
stream. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The stream provider of type
'MyStreamProvider' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentException:
Illegal characters in path.
at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
at System.Net.Http.MultipartFileStreamProvider.GetStream(HttpContent parent, HttpContentHeaders headers)
at System.Net.Http.MimeBodyPart.GetOutputStream()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Http.MimeBodyPart.GetOutputStream()
at System.Net.Http.MimeBodyPart.<WriteSegment>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Net.Http.HttpContentMultipartExtensions.<MultipartReadAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Http.HttpContentMultipartExtensions.<MultipartReadAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Net.Http.HttpContentMultipartExtensions.<ReadAsMultipartAsync>d__0`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at MyApp.Api.Controllers.SweepController.<EnterSweep>d__0.MoveNext()
```

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I have seen weird things happen on some of the Galaxy phones (only) with HTML rendering too. It doesn't surprise me really, but I think more information is needed here to offer a real solution. Might I suggest a few things to help you on your way?

1. Write the file name to your logging, then you can see if your suspicion is correct. It may be that the Galaxy is not handling a specific character well, and that should be immediately obvious.
2. Add a mask and validation to your user inputs. Doing number one first may give you a better idea of why this works, but in general it's a good idea to make sure that you have masked inputs to prevent troublesome or malicious input. It should also be validated on the server as much as possible. There's lots of JS masks out there, what works for you will largely depend on your use case.

If you do figure out what it is that is causing your issue or obtain more detail, please post back.